# Google Picker API for Google Workspace users only

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-picker

**Hi, I want the users of our organization only to use google picker to select files from their google drive.**

I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) example to set up API key and oAuth client in the google developer console.

Here is the summary of what I did:

- Enabled Google Picker API in Google API Console
- Created API Key
- Created OAuth client

Using [Official Example](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) google picker is working but it allows all Gmail users as well, I want to allow only those emails which belong to my domain.

I could not found anything related to this in official docs so I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it possible to bypass the consent screen using service account impersonation(User Access Token generated on the server via impersonation)?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is possible. 2. Yes it is possible.

Comment: @Morfinismo Thanks for your help. By generating an access token on the server-side for the user I'm able to avoid the consent screen. But the picker dialog doesn't work if the user is not logged in, I get the following message in the popup "In order to select an item from your online storage, please sign in.". Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I haven't check into that. I'll do some tests during the weekend and if you haven't gotten to a conclusion by then, I will come back and provide my input.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Morfinismo, I'll be looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Hope you're doing good @Morfinismo, the issue I reported earlier was occurring on the dev environment(localhost) after deploying I'm no more getting that error message. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a high level explanation, but the idea is the following:

1. Using a server side script, you will generate a token for a user using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) and [impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts).
2. On the client side, you will have to call that script on the server side and have the server return the token.
3. When initializing the picker, you will set the token to what you received from the server using the `PickerBuilder.setOAuthToken()` method.

That way you not only bypass the consent screen, but also make sure the drive picker presents the drive files of the user you authenticated with the service account.

If you are looking for a low level explanation, edit your question and post your architecture along with your code.